# Mapeamento de tabelas Associativas com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com o seguinte problema: Um cliente tem tarefas para cada dia da semana.

**Exemplo:**

> Cliente A - Sábado - Lavar Carro, Limpar Casa...

Mapeie da seguinte forma:

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DiaSemana> DiasSemana { get; set; }
}

public class DiaSemana
{
    public DiaSemana()
    {
        Tarefas = new List<Tarefa>();
        Clientes = new List<Cliente>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Dia { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Tarefa> Tarefas { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
}

public class Tarefa
{
    public Tarefa()
    {
        DiasSemana = new List<DiaSemana>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DiaSemana> DiasSemana { get; set; }
}
```

Quando comecei a popular o banco, utilizando o `Entity Framework`, virou uma confusão e comecei a ver que o `Entity Framework` entendeu tudo errado rs (`EF` burro rs)...

Sei que o jeito que mapeie está incorreto, mas não estou conseguindo perceber como posso estar mapeando as classes corretamente.

Edit:

O EF criou as seguintes tabelas:

Tarefa

```
Id          Nome
1           Lavar Louça
2           Limpar Casa
```

TarefaDiaSemana

```
Treafa_Id        DiaSemana_Id
1                2
2                2
```

DiaSemana

```
Id             Dia
1              Segunda
2              Terça
3              Quarta
```

DiaSemanaCliente

```
DiaSemana_Id         Cliente_Id
2                    99
2                    66
```

Cliente

```
Id        Nome
99        Diego
66        Felipe
```

Neste caso o banco está assumindo que Diego e Felipe tem as duas tarefas. Porém Diego de terça tem apenas a tarefa de Lavar Louça e Felipe apenas a tarefa de Limpar Casa.

No meu entendimento precisava do id cliente na tabela TarefaDiaSemana

Comment: Não entendi seu problema. O mapeamento está correto. O que estaria errado?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez editei a pergunta, ficou mais claro o problema agora.

Comment: Ah, agora que eu vi. Falta de atenção minha. Vou responder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto aqui está errado:

```
public class DiaSemana
{
    public DiaSemana()
    {
        Tarefas = new List<Tarefa>();
        Clientes = new List<Cliente>();
    }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Tarefa> Tarefas { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

Em primeiro lugar, isto não precisa:

```
    public DiaSemana()
    {
        Tarefas = new List<Tarefa>();
        Clientes = new List<Cliente>();
    }
```

O Entity Framework inicializa as propriedades de navegação pra você. Este código não faz diferença alguma para a aplicação.

Em segundo lugar:

```
public class DiaSemana
{    
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Tarefa> Tarefas { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

Se `DiaSemana` é a entidade que associa `Tarefas` e `Clientes`, ela não pode ter N `Tarefas` e N `Clientes`, afinal, ela associa apenas uma `Tarefa` com apenas um `Cliente`.

Mude para o seguinte:

```
public class DiaSemana
{    
    [Key]
    public int DiaSemanaId { get; set; }
    // Importante incluir os campos de chave estrangeira também!
    [Index("IUQ_DiaSemana_TarefaId_ClienteId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int TarefaId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_DiaSemana_TarefaId_ClienteId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual Tarefa Tarefa { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.

Comment: Então para eu estar recuperando todas as tarefas de um determinado cliente seria: `var tarefas = cliente.DiasSemana.Where(x=>x.Dia == "Segunda").ToList();`

Comment: É, na verdade, considerando por dia, seria: `var tarefas = cliente.DiasSemana.Where(x=>x.Dia == "Segunda").SelectMany(x => x.Tarefas).ToList();`

Comment: Show... Seria melhor eu criar talvez um `enum` para não precisar ficar lotantdo o banco com um monte de string como "segunda", "terça", e sim como como 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Sim, é o que eu usaria no seu lugar.